# Android - onBackPressed has no effect from fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-navigation

I have one Activity with a viewpager in it and also a frameLayout which is used as a container for fragments that should be drawn above this viewpager.

When I click a button of my Activity a fragment is shown in that framelayout container. On a press in the navigation bar I can close this fragment. All these things work fine when called from the activity itself.

I have now the situation that on a specific action from one of the fragments in the viewpager I invoke a callback which the main activity implements and then shows a fragment in the frame layout.

But here now comes the problem. When I want to navigate back or rather want to close the fragment like I described before, nothing happens.

So in conclusion:

1. "Fragment show to container" invoked from Activity directly -> I can navigate back from the fragment by getActivity().onBackpressed()
2. "Fragment show to container" invoke from fragment in viewpager and then delegated to activity -> The navigation back or getActivity().onBackpressed() has no effect.

So my question is: How can I close the fragment in the container even when I call it from one the fragments inside the viewpager of the activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile I found the problem..
Due to the fact that I am running some kind of update loop, I added the fragments multiple times to the backstack but didn't realize it because the fragment itself didn't change, the new instances just got added to the backstack. So when I called the onBackpressed() method the instances got removed from the backstack but because there were like 200 of them nothing happened.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are *adding* a fragment to the backstack, so `onBackPressed` you should *pop* last fragment from the backstack.

Something like that:

`FragmentManager fm = activity.getFragmentManager();
fm.popBackStackImmediate();`